# Gitlab only: variables multiple

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

is there anyway to do multiple AND variable expression?

let's say

```yaml
    .template1:
      only:
        variables:
          - $flag1 == "true"
    
    .template2:
      only:
        variables:
          - $flag2 == "true"
    
    job1:
      extends:
        - .template1
        - .template2
      script: echo "something"
```

How will this get evaluated?

- Is this going to result in only:variables overwriting each other thus template2 is the final result?
- or is this going to result in a combined variables such that it becomes an OR statement

```yaml
    only:
      variables:
        - $flag1 == "true"
        - $flag2 == "true"
```

Is there anyway to make it as and AND statement instead? `keeping the templating system`, and without using `rules: if` since using rules if has its own quirk, triggering multiple pipeline during merge request

Comment: Just following up. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: yeah.. it makes sense to use different attribute to make it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

Any time two jobs get "merged", either using `extends` or `anchors`, GitLab will overwrite one section with another. The sections don't actually get merged. In your case, you're extending from two jobs, so GitLab will completely overwrite the first `variables` section with the second.

### Solution

One way to achieve your desired result is by defining the variables in your template jobs. The problem you will have then is the two `variables` sections will overwrite each other. So..

You can use a `before_script` section to define the variable in the 2nd template. This approach works for your specific case of 2 templates. You can use `script` and `after_script` if you need a third template, buy you'd have to use a more advanced approach if you need more templates than that.

```yaml
    .template1:
      # We can define a variables section here, no problem
      variables:
        flag1: "true"
    
    .template2:
      # You can't define a second variables section here, since it will overwrite the first
      # Instead, define the environment variable directly in a before-script section
      before_script:
        - export flag2="true"
    
    job1:
      extends:
        - .template1
        - .template2
      only:
        variables:
          - $flag1 == "true"
          - $flag2 == "true"
      script: echo "something"
```